# Scraping a website returns an unexpected empty value in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am trying to scrape a player count on a website but my code keeps returning empty. What did I do wrong?

I'm trying to scrape this website: https://www.game-state.com/193.203.39.13:7777/ and the value I want to console.log is Players: x/1000

```
setInterval(function() {
  var url = 'https://www.game-state.com/193.203.39.13:7777/';
  request(url, function(err, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var players = $('.value #players');
    var playersText = players.text();
    console.log(playersText);
  })
}, 300)
```

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong.

You are selecting any tag with ID `players` that is *inside* of a tag with class `value`. What you want is both checks on the same element. The issue is the space between `.value` and `#players` - remove it: `.value#players`.

A tip: Try it in your browser first... go to the page, open devtools, enter `document.querySelector('.value #players')` - you'll see it comes back empty. With `.value#players` it works.

But, since an ID is supposed to be unique, just the ID `#players` would suffice anyway.